# NSTimer does not fire in KILLED background

Tags: ios, background, nstimer

I've developed an iOS app that uses geofences in the background. When such event happens, I want to send an HTTP request. If that request fails, I want to retry it several times with some seconds of delay between the calls. I am using `UIBackgroundMode` for 'location' already.

My `NSTimer` scheduled looks like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateFence:) userInfo:fence repeats:NO];
});
```

This works fine in foreground and 'normal' background, but not if the app is  killed and is started by iOS for a new geofence event. In that case the first http call works but when I then start the `NSTimer` with 30s delay it will never call the target selector.

Is there anything, beside `UIBackgroundMode`, that I need to use to be able to use `NSTimer` in (killed-) background? Am I scheduling the Timer on the wrong runloop/thread for that special background mode to work?

Answer (score 1):

when it is killed, it is killed. timers won't work - end of story - sorry

---

**alternatives might be** background app refreshes or silent pushes OR a user-visible local notification

Comment: Fun fact: when it is killed, you can execute code. But it looks like you cannot use Timers then. I already have the user-visible local notification. But leaving a geofence and being offline happens too often at the same time (since you are leaving wifi at the same time and switching to mobile) so it would be great for the UX, when I try to resend the message at least 2 or 3 times. But thanks for your answer, it looks like there is no impovement possible then. You can listen to geochange, try to send an http request, if it fails, thats it. Very bad for usability.

Comment: well you need more time right after the request? call beginBackgroundTask then!?

Comment: or use NSURLSession as the requests can proceed when killed IIRC

Comment: I'm using NSURLSession, but my current approach is: NSURLSession -> fail -> NSTimer schedule in 30 seconds -> NSURLSession, so the problem is not with the http call itself but with calling a method that will call NSURLSession

Comment: But your other comment with beginBackgroundTask could be the missing thing. I will try it out, if I understand it correctly, I would do beginBackgroundTask->NSURLSession->fail->NSTimer 30s->NSURLSession->fail->NSTimer 30s->NSURLSession->OK->endBackgroundTask

Comment: sorry I didn't volunteer this. Your question does quite explicitly ask about NSTimer.